# How can I change flash player version in flash cs6?

Tags: flash-cs6

Am using flash cs6.Currently am using flash player 11.2 now i want to change flash player 11.2 to flash player 15.How can i update.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to **http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html**
   and scroll down to the section **Playerglobal.swc archives - Developers only** and download the **[Flash Player 15](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/playerglobal/playerglobal15_0.swc)** SWC file
2. Rename that file to **playerglobal.swc** and copy it (dont paste yet)
3. Go to Flash CS6 folder within **Program Files** folder (well you never said.. for PC or MAC?) - Go into subfolders: Common --> Configuration --> ActionScript 3.0
4. In that "ActionScript 3.0" folder make a new one called **FP_15** and now paste the downloaded & renamed **playerglobal.swc** in there

> For Flash to know that this new file exists the next steps is to
>   update a config file (an XML file)

5. Go back one folder level and into  Common --> Configuration --> Players 
    and find + copy FlashPlayer11_2.xml. Paste this copy and rename to **FlashPlayer15_0.xml**. Now open it with Notepad or some similar basic text editor and change the following 3 lines...

`<player id="FlashPlayer15.0" version="26" asversion="3">`

`<name> Flash Player 15.0 </name>`

`<playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP15_0/playerglobal.swc" />`

Now inside Flash you can check by going to **Publish Settings** you can see under "Flash" section there is Flash player 15