# Updating Adobe Flash Pro CS6 to the latest Flash Player 23?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, swc

I read this post where someone asked
[How can I change flash player version in flash cs6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858209/how-can-i-change-flash-player-version-in-flash-cs6) and there was an answer instructing him how to add Flash Player 15, so I figured I could do something similar with Flash Player 23, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Does Adobe not provide a FlashPlayer23_0.xml file themselves? There are lots of lines in there, and copying one of the older xml files and editing a couple of them as the guide suggests doesn't seem right. In one of the lines I'm supposed to edit, I'm not sure what to put in for the version of FlashPlayer23.0.

```
<player id="FlashPlayer23.0" version="XX" asversion="3">
```

After doing all that, in Flash Pro I now see a "Flash Player 23" in the Target dropdown of the Publish section, and I have that selected, but when I actually publish, I get an error when I try to use one of the newer Flash features.

I'm actually just trying to use the new [removeAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#removeAt()) Array method where you can remove one element of an array by its index. It says you need at least Flash Player 19 for it to work. Here is my test code:

```
var a:Array = [0,1,2];
a.removeAt(1);
trace(a);
```

If I try that out with Flash Player 11 as the publish setting, I get the following expected error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: removeAt is not a function.
```

If I set it to publish to Flash Player 23, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::removeAt not found on Array and there is no default value.
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)**

> In one of the lines I'm supposed to edit, I'm not sure what to put in
>   for the version of FlashPlayer 23.0.

Always look for something called "release notes" for your version and it will tell you the number. The FlashPlayer 23.0 [**release notes**](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_23_air_23_release_notes.html#authoring_guidelines) (see **Authoring Guidelines** section) say :

> *To use the new Flash Player, you will need to target SWF version 34 by
>   passing "-swf-version=34"...*

Set that as : `<player id="FlashPlayer23.0" version="34" asversion="3">`

**(2)**

> I get an error when I try to use one of the newer Flash features

Did you actually replace the existing older **playerglobal.swc** file with the newest downloaded one (for FP 23.0 features)? The compiler needs the latest Flash Player file placed in the installation folders.

Remember installing the plugin from Adobe website is just for benefit of browsers, you still need to manually setup the installed Flash CC or CS software with the latest SWC file so that the compiler understands these new commands/features.

Comment: Thank You @VCOne  You answered the question before I post the question :)